# Read the first line of a bufferedInputStream and then the rest sepereatly

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I have an BufferedinputStream that contains the byte[] representation of a file file and before that it contains the name of file ("FileName.fileExtension")
I'd like to read the first line and then read the byte representation of the file so I can Convert It to the it's extension 
I tried this but it didn't work and because i have to keep the byte[] representation of the file

```
BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(sr.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sr.getInputStream()));
    String Filename=in.readLine();
    String y=in.lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Hint: `in.readLine()` is wrong. Try to find another solution for reading the file, stream, resource...

Comment: @zlakad I actually use IOUtils from Apache 
     byte[] x = IOUtils.toByteArray(bis);
But I cannot get the first line when using it

Comment: I don't use `Apache byte`, but I suggest that you read the first line, than get rid of it, and than use `Apache byte` for the rest of file

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to always use streams but you need to close the resources. Maybe what you want can be achieved with standard `Scanner` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
String fileName = null;
byte[] content = null;

try (InputStream in = sr.getInputStream()) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(in); // might have to call useDelimiter()
  fileName = s.nextLine(); // skips line delimiter from the stream

  ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  int read;
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];
  while ((read = in.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
    buf.write(data, 0, read);
  }
  content = buf.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
//Read all the lines first.
List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(Filename)).collect(Collectors.toList());
//Store the first line in a header
String header = lines.stream().findFirst().get();
//Store the remaining lines in a list of lines.
lines.stream().skip(1).forEach(s -> data.add(s));
```

Comment: OP wants to read first line as the line, **and the rest** of file like byte[]

Comment: I guess I haven't made my self clear 
I Recieve an Input stream containing the file name in this example ABK.png and then the byte[] representation of the file 
i'd like to Extract the name and then the rest of the input keeping it in it's byte format (not String so I won't have any problems in Converting to the file original format).
 
ABK.png‰PNG

   
IHDR     
    È–˜   sBITÛáOà    IDATxœìy@×úþg²°Â¾Cd0àŠ¨ ˆR‘
îz]âÞk[…Zj´×ªmE´­ÖÔ.Ö]+"¢€UQ«²

.  „5l

Comment: So if you are already getting the filename and byte array separately, how do they get mixed up?